# Notepad++ - change escape character

Tags: regex, escaping, notepad++

In PL\SQL code which I am editing with Notepad++ I have following:

```
where REGEXP_SUBSTR (a.val, '(\d+)\', 1, 1, NULL, 1) = b.key
```

Because of `\'` Notepad++ does not interpret `'` as quote closure and rest of source do not have syntax coloring - it has grey color like quoted text.
Is there any way to tell Notepad++ to do not interpret `\` as escape character, thus `\'` will be interpreted as valid end of quote?
I was searching program preferences, but without any success.

**EDIT**
Strange. When I open new new file, type this line, choose *Language > S > SQL* then text is highlighted OK. But when I change tab and then return I have bad coloring again.  Choosing *Language > S > SQL* again makes no difference.

Comment: How `\'` would be a valid end quote? Could you find the ends in `'foo\'bar\'` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj It is PLSQL, so you should write: `'foo\''bar\'`. `\\` is not escape in PLSQL and I would like Notepad++ to interpret it the same way.

Comment: Choose **Language** > **S** > **SQL**, see [what it looks like](http://imgur.com/6rHDzSY).

Comment: @stribizhev I edited question

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: If the last character of the regular expression is a real backslash them perhaps the string should be `'(\d+)\\'`.

Answer (score 10):

There is now an option in Notepad++ (since 2014-05-11) to ignore backslash as an escape character for SQL.

Uncheck the box at 'Settings' - 'Preferences' - 'MISC.' - 'Treat backslash as escape character for SQL'

(In v7.7.1, at least, you need to restart np++ for this change to take effect.)

Comment: I'm using Notepad++ 7.8.7, and the "Treat backslash as escape" option has been moved to Settings-Preferences-Language

Answer (score 1):

In case of Oracle PL/SQL I've changed escape character after e.g. character E
from:

```
LIKE 'E\_%' ESCAPE '\'
```

to:

```
LIKE 'E?_%' ESCAPE '?'
```

which did the trick. Not a solution, but if the escape character change is OK, it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Choose Language > User-Defined and after choose Language > S > SQL.

Reload current SQL language correct the bug.

BR